# Issue in Rendering huge data in Excel output format for SSRS SDK PHP

Tags: php, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012

How can i change the SSRS SDK output excel format rendering from, 1997-2003 worksheet format to latest worksheet format (ie from xls to xlsx format). The prior format fails in rendering huge datas with rows more than 65356 rows.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why this is tagged `php`?

Comment: Yes, as i uses ssrs sdk php code.

Comment: But you've not shown anything in your question that relates to PHP in any way: no code, nothing to indicate how you're using the ssrs php sdk

Answer (score 0):

This post is a bit old but the solution may help someone.

To change the excel format used in [PHP SSRS SDK](http://ssrsphp.codeplex.com/) from the 1997-2003 to the 2007+ version, change the following line in bin/RenderType/RenderAsEXCEL.php file

```
public function GetFormat()
{
    return "EXCEL";
}
```

to

```
public function GetFormat()
{
    return "EXCELOPENXML";
}
```

Ideally, you could

1. Make a copy of the RenderAsEXCEL.php file
2. Rename to say RenderAsOPENEXCEL.php
3. Change the GetFormat function as above.
4. Change the Class name to say RenderAsOPENEXCEL
5. Add this new file to the SSRSReport.php file after require_once 'RenderType/RenderAsXML.php';

   require_once 'RenderType/RenderAsOPENEXCEL.php';

**PS**: This only works with **Reporting Services 2012 and above**.